# how to maintain the required order in mongoose pagination?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

Hi i was using mongoose pagination package on Field collection .

```
Field.paginate({Survey: ObjectId("5a94f3c5a26762239734fcc6")}, {
                    select: '_id name',
                    lean: true,
                    leanWithId: false,
                    page: paginationParams.page, //2
                    limit: paginationParams.limit //4
                })
```

once i do this i am i am getting the field documents whos Field collection Id's are random as shown below:

//in first page

```
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4") , name : "ddd");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5") , name : "eee");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3") , name : "ccc");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1" , name : "aaa");
```

//in second page

```
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6") , name : "fff");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7") , name : "ggg");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8") , name : "hhh");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2") , name : "bbb");
```

How ever i want to give a predefined order for field collection  id s so that the pagination returns the similar order once the pagination is done 
as shown below
//first page

```
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1") , name : "aaa");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2") , name : "bbb");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3") , name : "ccc");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4") , name : "ddd");
```

//second page

```
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5"), name : "eee");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6"), name : "fff");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7"), name : "ggg");
{ _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8"), name : "hhh");
```

Is this possible to order by Field collection IDs  ? if yes where and how can i mention the order of these ids?

Comment: sort can work here but not sure about text based values

Comment: can add query you tried?

Comment: query as in $in?

Comment: i have edited the _id . it is ObjectId

Comment: Do you want to _order_ by Id or Name?

Comment: i want to order by id